# How to narrowing a single property on an object

Tags: typescript

How does one narrow a single property on an object?

```js
type Foo = { 
  a: number | undefined
  b: string
}

let foo: Foo 
foo = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 'b'
}

// function accepts only narrowed version of Foo
const fn = (arg: Foo & { a: number })=>console.log(arg.a)

if(foo.a!==undefined){
  // compiler should know foo's type is now { a: number, b: string }
  fn(foo)
}
```

One solution would be to manual override the type as follows:

```js
fn(foo as Foo & { a: number })
```

However is there a better way?

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBYAUFKBDALigDsBXAWwCMIAnKAHylOIBMIAzAS2Ihe10pEAzsBrcA5tgC+2bABsIwKOwRF4ibCsQp0-fEQCMAGj2CoAckrnpsrAHo7y5gGNgnOMXzPnEMMCFQHnIgJHg0NHAA7rxQAG60Qu6ecOywCNjOHiLKnigAFGHiaghQAGRo+iQU1HRSAJRIAHyZxEJwCgB0cnDiBTTiHXh1tpzseVqDAIRISMxsXDwsdah6DlCZ5GCcCnRCABZwpHIsUADWxFHKCOYBoJBQnAEXkRWEVVS0UDI4OeMIwz81h5oG05KQ3B49OxiH9EHgAuoyq8iGQPrUAVIgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not narrow object types based on conditional checks on object properties. You could achieve this by creating a user-defined type guard that checks on typeof `Foo.a` like following:

```
type Foo = { 
  a: number | undefined
  b: string
}
//custom type guard using type predicate
function fooHasA(obj: Foo): obj is Foo & {
    a: Exclude<Foo["a"], undefined>
} {
    return typeof obj.a !== 'undefined';
}

let foo: Foo 
foo = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 'b'
}

// function accepts only narrowed version of Foo
const fn = (arg: Foo & { a: number })=>console.log(arg.a)

if(fooHasA(foo)){
  // compiler knows now that foo's type is now { a: number, b: string }
  fn(foo)
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBYAUFKBDALigDsBXAWwCMIAnKAHylOIBMIAzAS2Ihe10pEAzsBrcA5tgC+2APSyAxqRFxyUUJCjjSeGiyZCJ68NDA1enBXmARs7ZguCc4xKOwQAJPEICCACjhKACsieDgASiJAoKhOIVgEKAAyNH5cfCIAUQAPBQAbUjYAHjCAbQAiPHKAXQAaJlYObl4APmlUnHTzYFIaVw0IOHYoaIA6PCgAQiQUAHJmNi4eFlmAbmlsbDyIYDcEUMS7RJR0NMIoAEZatMEoWcpZjaw5WTcHJxd8BQUIMGB4lx5EAkXQ0OAAd14UAAbrRDJ8hgk4NgFC4RG5XCg-LpxAdECl0OcyFRaFApOEkC1UcQhHBtqM8nBxNiaOJxuFNlhOOw-O44F5fLyEOFwqg0vIoKjyGBONs6ABrYgQ+JK8HqAAW1j2cFm8QGsRVELQGRIFGoNHqtxEYmI4jJaXYxCFESeQA)

Also, you don't need to create new types just for the sake of narrowing an object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need `a` the obvious thing to do is to redefine your function to take a number.

```
const fn = (arg: number)=>console.log(arg)

if(foo.a){
  fn(foo.a)
}
```

Another option is to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
// define a new type just to make things tidy
type FooWithA = Foo & { a:number }

function isFooWithA(obj: Foo): obj is FooWithA {
    return obj.a !== undefined;
}

const fn = (arg: FooWithA)=>console.log(arg.a)

if(isFooWithA(foo)) {
  fn(foo);
}
```

What might be best is to rethink your types to eliminate the optional parameter.

```
type A = {
    a: number
}

type B = {
    b: string
}

type AB = A & B

const fn = (arg: A)=>console.log(arg.a)

const foo: AB = {
    a: 1,
    b: "two"
};
fn(foo)
```

A more detailed example is necessary to know which you should use.